# deterministic expression of stochastic integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $(M_t)$ be a non-negative martingale on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \{ \mathcal{F}_n \} , \mathbb{P})$. Let $dM_t = M_t dW_t$. How can we write the following
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} [\sqrt{M_T}| \mathcal{F}_t],
\end{equation}
where $0 \leq t \leq T$, in terms of a deterministic function $F(t,T,M_t)$?

Comment: Why should the square-root be well-defined? In general, $\int_0^T M_{\tau} \, dW_{\tau} \geq 0$ does *not* hold.

Comment: @saz See my edit above. This was the original question I got.

Comment: That's geometric Brownian motion, so what was the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Solve the stochastic differential equation $$dM_t = M_t \, dW_t$$ in order to find an explicit formula for $M_t$ in terms of $t$ and $W_t$.